# Docker / NGINX / Network Share

Tags: docker, nginx, containers, share

I've a container with an image of NGinx, I've update apt and install smbclient also.

I try to access to a shared windows folder on my network, which contains some datas (xml/Json) regulary updated.

I try to connect to the client with smbclient, username, domain, and password : No problemo ;)

But I cannot do mount this shared folder on my NGinx container with command :

`mount -t cifs //[WindowsIP]/MySharedFolder /var/sharewin -o user=[Username],dom=[Domain],password=[ClearPassword]`

Of course /var/sharewin exist
But I have this message : mount /var/sharewin: permission denied

I don't understand because I use the terminal of NGinx directly

Sorry for my noob question, certainly answered 1M times, I have search and try many many solutions but nothing

Thank's

Access to shared folder

Comment: Welcome to SO ! I recommend you post examples of what you tried and results so other won't ask you to reproduce what you already did as it will improve the question.